# ASP.NET 5 (i.e. Core 1.0) Immutable Configuration

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, configurationmanager

I can't get ASP.NET 5 (i.e. Core 1.0) to work with immutable configuration classes.

Let me demonstrate first using a mutable class.

#### config.json

```
{
  "Name": "Lou",
  "Age": 30
}
```

#### Config.cs (mutable)

```
   public class Config
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }
```

#### Registration in Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var configBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddJsonFile("config.json");

    var config = configBuilder.Build();
    services.Configure<Config>(config);

    services.AddMvc();
}
```

The code above works well and the values of `Config.Name` and `Config.Age` are as expected.

But once I change `Config`'s property setters to private, they are no longer set by the configuration builder:

```
public class Config
{
    public string Name { get; private set; } // == null
    public int Age { get; private set; } // == 0
}
```

I would have expected ASP.NET 5 to use reflection and set the properties like it does with ASP.NET 4, instead of simply ignoring them.  Am I missing something?

I created a sample project to demonstrate: https://github.com/johnnyoshika/mvc6-immutable-config
The `master` branch uses a mutable `Config` class while the `immutable-config` branch uses an immutable `Config` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ConfigurationBinder` object doesn't set private properties: https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration/blob/ba1d9b4cbc363db9318f201f08fbfecc72e7922b/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder/ConfigurationBinder.cs#L64-L82

Here's an issue tracking that: https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration/issues/394

One way to workaround this is to create an interface with getters only that's implemented by your `Config` code. Then, you can use that in your code.

Comment: As a caution, an interface doesn't actually buy you immutability, since it can easily be cast away. One, not particularly obscure, corner of C# where you can do this without thinking is in the variable declaration of a `foreach` loop. OTOH, you're not very likely to have `IEnumerable<Config>`. It's all how well you want to sleep at night.